# Why is strcasecmp not working?

Tags: php, strcmp

I am doing a string comparison in php, but `strcasecmp` always outputs that the strings are not equal.

Here is my code:

```
    <?php

function multiexplode($delimiters,$string) {

    $ready = str_replace($delimiters, $delimiters[0], $string);
    $launch = explode($delimiters[0], $ready);
    return  $launch;
}

$owner = "Musica no tAatro: venha ja";
$owner_keys = multiexplode(array(".",":"," "),$owner);
$musica_c = array("musica","teatro");
$musica = 0;

  if(sizeof($owner_keys) > 1){
        foreach($musica_c as $key_c){
                foreach($owner_keys as $cat){
                    if(strcasecmp($cat,$key_c)==0){
                        ++$musica;
                    }else{
                        echo "do not match<br>"; 
                    }
                }
            }
        }
?>
```

Why does `strcasecmp` detect different strings?

Comment: have you tried `===` ??

Comment: Do both of the compares fail or only the tAatro (shouldn't that be teatro)?

Comment: yes i've tried {===} and this doesn't work either.Yes both fails.

Comment: should rather be `$musica++;`

Comment: It is matching 1 string which is `Musica` & `musica`. Just ` echo $musica;` in the end. However, another string is different which is `tAatro` & `teatro`. That is why not matching.

Comment: that means your strings are not equal :)

Answer (score 1):

`strcasecmp` is doing its work properly.

It is matching one pair of string which is `Musica` & `musica`. Just `echo $musica;` in the end. However, another string pair is different which is `tAatro` & `teatro`. That is why not matching.

It is expected behavior.

Comment: sorry, but strcasecmp is not doing its work properly because when i echo $musica outputs 0. And outputs on every comparison "do not match".

Comment: I am getting 1 by just running your PHP code with added `echo $musica;`. Try running code in http://phpfiddle.org/lite